# How to handle a pthread_mutex_unlock() error?

Tags: c++, error-handling, pthreads

I'm developing a thread-safe class that also handle errors. I was wonder how to handle a possible error that come from the function pthread_mutex_unlock(). If I throw the mutex is still locked? Should I try to unlock it again or destroy the class object?

```
int SomeClass::function() {   
    int res = pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    if(res < 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("lock failed: " + std::string(std::strerror(res)));
    // some code
    res = pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
    if(res < 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("unlock failed: " + std::string(std::strerror(res)));
    return something;
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

the vaiable `_mutex` is a protected class member (non static) initialized inside the constructor using only `pthread_mutex_init(&_mutex, NULL)`

Comment: What type of mutex is it?  I assume it belongs to `SomeClass` and is not global. Is it shared across multiple instances of `SomeClass`?  Answers to these questions will reveal: A) what errors might occur and B) what is the risk of destroying the object.  Have you considered `pthread_mutex_trylock()`?

Comment: See edit part. I think that If I use `pthread_mutex_trylock()` I also have to use `pthread_mutex_unlock()` so don't know how this could help.

Comment: I believe the only error from unlock() is calling it when you don't own the lock.  This would be a logic error in your code.  So log and throw. Tip: If your compiler supports it... add \_\_FILE__ or \_\_FILENAME__ or "compiler-dependent method of name of compilation unit" to your exception msg. If you're an overachiever look for the line number mechanism as well.

Comment: I did not read your title correctly.  Deleted previous comment.  You are asking about recovering from unlock() failures.  see above.  Unlock failures are logic errors (or mutex corruption).

Comment: Regarding lock() failures: I would not retry in your methods.  return a "busy" or "not now" error and allow the caller to retry.  Why?  You have no work to do during a retry mechanism and the caller may.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only case when pthread_mutex_unlock can definitely fail is when mutex being unlocked is not a valid mutex or mutex is not owned by your thread. So if neither is the case, you shouldn't worry, and both conditions are an application bug - at this point you can throw an exception and not worry about mutex state, you have a bigger problems.